# couldn't find an option for Airbnb typescript in react js ( next js ) in eslint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syYFI.png)

couldn't find an option for Airbnb typescript in react js ( next js ) in eslint , before this happened I install the storybook and  click yes on option to migrate eslint  storybook

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this installation can help you https://github.com/storybookjs/eslint-plugin-storybook . I belive  @eslint/config not ask directly storybook , after your question I also try `npm init @eslint/config` in a project but it also not ask storybook to me.

Other than that if you use ts,react and storybook you may use dts https://weiran-zsd.github.io/dts-cli/ .

Comment: the problem now is every time in any project  whenever  npm init @eslint/config there is no google/Airbnb option for popular guide I don't know why I try to switch to from 16 node version to 17 and  still same